# IRC connection errors on a comedicly simple python program

Tags: python, irc

I started out today trying to make a relatively complex program involving IRC logs. No matter what I've done, I've been getting:

```
['ERROR', ':Closting', 'Link:', *******identifying details**********,'(Connection', 'timed', 'out')'
```

I figured simplifying everything would help me learn down from up, but even with this extraordinarily easy program, I'm  still getting that error:

```
import sys
import socket
import string

HOST="irc.freenode.net"
PORT=6667
NICK="nick"
IDENT="nick"
REALNAME="realname"
readbuffer=""

s=socket.socket( )
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send("".join(["NICK",NICK,"\r\n"]).encode())
s.send("".join(["USER %s %s bla :%s\r\n" % (IDENT, HOST, REALNAME)]).encode())

while 1:
    readbuffer=readbuffer+s.recv(1024).decode()
    temp=str.split(readbuffer, "\n")
    readbuffer=temp.pop( )

    for line in temp:
        line=str.rstrip(line)
        line=str.split(line)
        if(line[0]=="PING"):
            s.send("".join(["PONG ",line[1], "\r\n"]).encode())
        print (line)
```

I'm at the point I'm pretty sure I'm exactly aping the the dummy code people have posted here (and pretty much everywhere else. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welome to Stack Overflow. +1 for knowing that 'simplifying everything would help me learn down from up'. So many people don't do that crucial step.

Comment: It's easy thing to pick up when you make as many mistakes as I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at this line of code:

```
s.send("".join(["NICK",NICK,"\r\n"]).encode())
```

If you replaced `s.send` with `print`, you’d realize it was sending strings like this:

```
NICKnick<CR><LF>
```

There’s no space!  That makes it an invalid command, and makes registration fail. At some point, the server gives up on receiving a valid registration from you, and so sends you an error and closes the connection. So make sure you include a space:

```
s.send("".join(["NICK ",NICK,"\r\n"]).encode())
```

At least then you’d be sending a valid registration.

Comment: Thanks so much. That was it. I was so busy assuming that it hinged on something I didn't understand that I missed that space.